# Undefined control sequence error when using includepdf

Tags: pdfpages

I'm using a customized `includepdf` command to insert .pdfs into a document. Following is the customisation of the `includepdf` command.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}   
\newcommand{\includepdfframed}[1]{\includepdf[
            keepaspectratio,
            trim=3mm 3mm 3mm 3mm,
            frame,
            pages=-,
            scale=.75,
            offset=-5mm -5mm,
            pagecommand={}
         ]
        } 
\end{document}
```

Then the usage of function is as follows.
`\includepdfframed{Appendices/pdfs/Appendix_A.pdf}`

It doesn't work and just shows like attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: where are you using the argument?

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: @user202729 I've updated the post with minimum working example and attached screenshot.

Comment: Make sure the MWE does give the output you show.

Comment: Yes, I've attached screenshot to the post, that's the output I am seeing.

Comment: Your so called "minimal working example" doesn't even load the pdfpages package, and never uses the the defined command. It most certainly does not have the output you say it has. You need to put in `\usepackage{pdfpages}` and add `{#1}` after `]` in the defined command so it actually uses the argument.

Comment: You didn't load package `pdfpages`. Also `\includepdfframed` should be defined by either `\newcommand\includepdfframed{\includepdf[...]}` or `\newcommand\includepdfframed[1]{\includepdf[...]{#1}}`.

Comment: @frabjous Thanks for pointing out. It works fine now.